# Need to hide Options with disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is a longshot however, I need to be able to hide options that are disabled based on the code below, for example option 2 has an attribute of disabled, I don't want this option to be displayed -

```
<select id="pa_machine-model" name="attribute_pa_machine-model">
        <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
        <option value="bestech-40" disabled="disabled">Bestech 40</option><option value="52">52</option>
</select>
```

I've managed this  in Firefox with CSS but in chrome they still appear but are greyed out, each variable has a lot of options so it would be better if they only showed dependant on the select box above. Is there a way to do with JavaScript/jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: It makes me wonder why you're applying a hidden display and a disabled state, isn't it best to just hide these elements instead of applying both disabled + hidden to them?

Comment: @Raptus website has been built in WordPress using WooCommerce - it's a project I've inherited and I'm really struggling with this part

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS:

```
option[disabled=disabled] {
    display:none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/X5Du2/)**

Comment: I've just tested, looks like it works on Windows 7 but not OSX Mavericks /:

Comment: @j08691 It certainly doesn't that disabled link is still visible.

Comment: @Raptus - OS and Chrome ver?

Comment: I see it as well.  Mac OSX 10.9.3 with Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114

Comment: Maybe it's a Mac thing. Does `option[disabled]` instead of `option[disabled=disabled]` make a difference there? On windows and linux it works.

Comment: @j08691 I've just tested Windows 7 and IE - Doesn't work on there either but that's Microsoft for you..

Comment: Well there's an interesting behaviour, @j08691 your code is correct, no doubts about that, the display none IS being applied, however disabled will still show visible.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this cross browser with CSS alone. I have had the same problem in the past.

One way to work around this is to wrap the disabled `option` in a span (using JQuery) and hide that:

```
$('option[disabled=disabled]').wrap('<span class="disabled" />');
```

---

```
.disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X5Du2/2/)

---

EDIT:

In light of comments below, since you probably don't want to start hacking wordpress plugins try this:

Every time a `select` is changed; run the script:

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
    $('option[disabled=disabled]').wrap('<span class="disabled" />');
});
```

Comment: This looks like the best option - but I can't get it to work with WP [http://www.cyanx.co.uk/shop/wash-up-blade]

Comment: Apparently display: none; works fine in FireFox, however in Chrome + IE it will not.

Comment: @brandudno Where are the disabled options on that page?

Comment: @Raptus this is so frustrating! If I can get it wrapped in a span like in the demo above ^^ then it should work! *fingers crossed*

Comment: @3rror404 the disabled attributes are added as you go down the drop down menus - hence my problem getting the span to wrap around them

Comment: Sadly, that still didn't work :( - didn't work on the fiddle either

Comment: That's wierd, doesn't for me are you on OSX?

Comment: @3rror404 - okay, I've got this far it removes the span after change is made to it's own select but I need it to apply the changes to all the form

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...  I just tried using jQuery .hide() method and that doesn't do anything either, even though it does show that the inline style is there:
[image]

You could remove the node entirely with: `$('option:disabled').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select id="pa_machine-model" name="attribute_pa_machine-model">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="bestech-40" class="hide">Bestech 40</option>
        <option value="52">52</option>
    </select>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >

    $( ".hide" ).hide();
    </script>
```